How can I find specific GPS coordinates in a blosm/ blender-osm import in the Blender model?
I have imported a terrain with blender-osm/ blender.
Now I would like to place my camera and some objects at specific GPS coordinates.
Due to showing the view from a mountain, the import spans a bigger area and finding these points manually seems to be impossible.
How can I e.g. place the 3D cursor to specific GPS coordinates?

Sorry but we can't answer questions about third-party addons which aren't built into Blender on this Q&A site.
